# Listing information from a column in a single cell, only if the info in the first column fits certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I'm trying to have the following outcome across two Google sheets, with a formula in cells F3, F4, G3, G4, etc.:

[image: Example of outcome]

I've tried to attack it a few different ways with no luck, thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably better suited for webapps.stackexchange.com as this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Use Double filter to cross the data and JOIN the results:
F3:

```
=JOIN(",",FILTER($A$3:$A,FILTER($B$3:$C,REGEXMATCH($B$2:$C$2,TO_TEXT($E3)))=RIGHT(F$2)))
```

[image]